# In JSTL/EL, how exactly are enum-to-string comparisons supposed to work?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, enums, jstl, resin

Given a JSP page, and some object bound to a request attribute called "foo", I can refer to "foo" with:

```
${foo}
```

If the value of "foo" has a bean property called, say, "type", and the type of "type" is some `enum` class, then to make comparisons I would use a string:

```
<c:if test='${foo.type == "WHATEVER"}'>
```

Then assuming that one of the constants in my `enum` class has the name "WHATEVER", that comparison should work, and produce either `true` or `false`.

Now what I'm wondering is how exactly that comparison is supposed to be carried out by the servlet container. Some Oracle documentation ([here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/gjddd/)) suggests (vaguely) that what happens is that the string constant is converted to the `enum` type, and then the comparison is made.

I'm investigating a situation involving code that I *think* works differently between Jetty/Tomcat (ie, Apache) and Resin.  The Apache world seems to be doing the right thing, or at least the thing that I'd expect according to that documentation from Oracle.

What I fear is that another property of my `enum` may be causing the Resin implementation to do something different. Specifically, my `enum` class has a `.toString()` implementation that returns a different string than that returned by `.name()`.  That quirk causes no problems in an Apache server, or at least none that I've ever seen. If Resin implements the comparison by converting the enum constant to a string (via `.toString()`, not `.name()`) instead of converting the string to the `enum` type, then things won't work consistently.

Note that in all other respects I'm having no issues with using my `enum` types (lots of them are like this) in various other ways in JSP/JSTL/EL. There are in fact only a small number of places where there's EL logic in the JSP, because the application does most of its work via client-side template rendering.

*edit* — I'm pretty sure I confirmed that Resin does the comparisons differently, though I don't know exactly what that is. I have (for reasons I don't recall) a "name" EL function in my own EL function library, so I can use that to work around the problem.

Comment: Have you tried <c:if test='${foo.type.name() == "WHATEVER"}'> to make sure the name() value is what is being used for the string comparison [assuming that it's the toString() quirk that's hanging you up]?

Comment: @alfreema yes, but my own Jetty (7.6.15; that's the newest one that I can get to work with a regular `.war` file) doesn't support that. My own EL function however does work around the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Resin is processing incorrectly. I've filed a bug at http://bugs.caucho.com/view.php?id=5925

Comment: Thanks; that's what I suspected. I've had other "interesting" type conversion issues with the EL in Resin before.